# Rails: Canned/RESTful way for accessing data returned by a method of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

In my app I have a User model which defines a history method that returns a list of Activity objects, showing the last N actions the user has carried out. The UserController#history method wires this with a view.

The code looks as follows:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def history
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    @history = user.history(20)
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities    

  def history(limit)      
      ...
  end
end
```

Naturally, I also added this line to my routes.rb file:

```
match '/user/:id/:action', :controller => 'user'
```

so now when I go to localhost:3000/user/8/history I see the history of user 8. Everything works fine.

Being a Rails NOOB I was wondering whether there is some canned solution for this situation which can simplify the code. I mean, if /user/8 is the RESTful way for accessing the page of User 8, is it possible to tell Rails that /user/8/history should show the data returned by invoking history() on User 8?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the convention to name controllers is in the plural form unless it is only for a single resource, for example a session.

About the routes I believe you used the `resources` "helper" in your routes, what you can do is specify that the resource routes to users also has a member action to get the history like this

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :history
  end
end
```

I think there is no cleaner way to do this

You can check it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Answer (score 0):

As far as the rails standards are concerned, it is the correct way to show the history in your case. In rails controllers are suppose to be middle-ware of views and model, so defining an action `history` seems good to me.

And you can specify the routes in better way as:

```
resources :user do
  get 'history', :on => :member #it will generate users/:id/history as url.
end
```